# Empty string supplied as input when parsing content

Tags: filters, content

I have this code:

```
<?php
function mb_find_my_image( $content ) {
    if( is_home() ) { /* if is home start */

      $dom = new domDocument;
      $dom->loadHTML($content);
      $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;


    } /* if is home end */
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'mb_find_my_image' );
?>
```

However, it seems that I always get the following error:

> Empty string supplied as input on line 6

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: I assume that line 6 is this one: `$dom->loadHTML($content);` ?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: What does `var_dump($content);` tell you? Add that as the first line inside the function.

Comment: null
string<html code></html code>...(length=805)

Comment: That is peculiar. That does not look like any `var_dump` output I have seen. I expected `string(123)"content content content"`. That `null` is especially interesting and do you actually have those `<html code>` tags or is that some kind of filler you made up? Either way, it looks like the string is not empty.

Comment: It's not literally <html code>, it's actually the post content, including the html code, but the error message remains. Also there's a line break after the null, followed by string" post content, post content, post content (you get the idea)"...(length=805), however the problem remains. I'm trying to make a workaround using var_export($content, true), maybe that would help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8384/discussion-between-s-ha-dum-and-mentalhead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem.

The main problem was that I was calling the function `mb_find_my_image` from `index.php`. After I've removed the calling from `index.php`, everything works as it should.